# Unable to click Settings link

Tags: selenium-webdriver

scenario is:
1. login to google calendar
2. click on on settings icon on the top right corner of the page
3. click the settings link

When I search the element using the xpath in firebug I am able to find 1 match for each of them. But during the script execution, it is able to click on the settings icon, but unable to click on the settings link. Below is the code to find and click settings icon and settings link

```
    //Select the settings icon : This is working
    driver.findElement(By
                            .xpath(".//*[@id='mg-settings']/div")).click();

//click on Settings link : This is not working even though element is available
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=':k']/div[text()=\"Settings\"]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the "s" at the end (you are using driver.findElement**s** instead of driver.findElement). Probably that is just a typo.

Also I would not recommend tie to IDs like ":k". They are dynamic and can be changed any time.

Based on the Google Calendar structure I would recommend trying the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*div[contains(@class, 'goog-menuitem')]/div[contains(@class, 'goog-menuitem-content') and text() = 'Settings']")).click();
```